# BigCommerce PHP hello world app installation error with silex

Tags: php, bigcommerce, silex

I am new to the bigcommerce development. I am trying to create a bigcommerce app in localhost XAMPP server. I am getting this error.

I have done making the localhost has https. created app in bigcommerce development by following this link https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex

I am looking for the help to fix this error.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're trying to access a path that doesn't exist (it's a 404 error). If you put it in a sub folder, make sure you configure that in your app as well. We don't know what your implementation, or file system, is though so it's hard to be more specific than that. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

So I think the issue with this one is versioning of PHP that is required to be used on the app is out of date and the requirements of Composer being needed doesn't support the version of PHP we utilize for the app, and that is the reason for all the listener and request errors. Dependencies are out of date for local hosting. For instance our package.lock file for the PHP Silex app requires PHP 5.3 to run as seen on line 24:

```
"require": {
                "php": ">=5.3.0"
            },
```

While for Composer and installing the dependencies that version of PHP isn't supported to work in tandem with Composer as seen in the installer on line 383:

```
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.2', '<')) {
        $errors['php'] = array(
            'Your PHP ('.PHP_VERSION.') is too old, you must upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 or higher.'
        );
    }
```

Furthermore either versions of PHP required to either run the App and or updated version of composer is no longer supported here are a list of no longer supported PHP versions. https://www.php.net/eol.php

We are currently working on updating this App to utilizing components that aren't deprecated like Silex components but in the meantime I recommend Switching to both a PHP version that is supported by PHP and by composer then trying to run the App.

Also if you are looking into php development on the Bigcommerce platform our PHP larvavel app has just had a recent overhaul you might have an easier time building with that repo.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I have PHP Version 7.4.33 then why could not run it in localhost.